# ble central and peripheral on bluez at the same time

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to make my linux board working ble central and peripheral at the same time.
I test it below step.
In bluetoothctl, I type the command "discoverable on".
Next, I type "advertise on".
Next, I connect that board using btgatt-client.
After connect, I try to scan ble RCU(HOGP).
I can find the RCU.
But I can't connect the RCU whenever it connected btgatt-client.

My bluetooth chip support bluetooth version 4.1.
It means “LE Link Layer Topology” support.
So, I think I can connect ble RCU(HOGP) and btgatt-client at the same time.
My bluez version is 5.50 and linux kernel is 4.9.

Is this impossible?
Any body know the reason?

Comment: What chip do you have? It's optional to support multiple roles at the same time.

Comment: Did you find a way to do that using Bluez? Can't find a answer on that as well...

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know , you can not act as central and peripheral at the same time for single device . It would be helpful if you would have attached output .
If in case you meant "act as central and peripheral simultaneously" then remember when you are connecting to a device you receive a connection object , in order to advertise and then later on scan from same device you need to use the same connection object otherwise device would not connect or disconnect for one or the other operation.
I would suggest you to rather code yourself in order to achieve desired results , there are many libraries avialable to do so.